# Перенос массива

Tags: javascript, php

у меня есть массив на php

```
$array = array( 'http://vinrarus.ucoz.net/D.gif', 'http://vinrarus.ucoz.net/D1.png', 'http://vinrarus.ucoz.net/D2.png', 'http://vinrarus.ucoz.net/D3.png', 'http://vinrarus.ucoz.net/D4.png', 'http://vinrarus.ucoz.net/D5.png');
```

как перенести его в массив на js.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "var array =";
echo json_encode($array);
echo ";";
```

Comment: Можно просто через запятую `echo str_1, str_2, ... и т.д`

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg конечно